# \maketitle I can't see Title and Authors in PDF

Tags: titles, overleaf, author, ieeeconf

Good morning, I don't understand why but if I use \maketitle I can't see Title and Authors in PDF. Can someone help me?
Thanks

```latex
\documentclass[conference,a4paper]{IEEEtran}

\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts


\usepackage{cite}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}

\usepackage{algorithmic}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}



\begin{document}


\title{………..\\

{\footnotesize \textsuperscript}

\thanks{}

}


\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{1\textsuperscript{nd} ……………}

\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{……………….} \\

\textit{………………}\\

…………….. \\

…………….}

\and

\IEEEauthorblockN{2\textsuperscript{nd} ………………}

\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{…………………..} \\

\textit{……………………..}\\

…………………….. \\

…………………..}

\maketitle

}

\begin{abstract}
.....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to do a title in LaTeX is to do it like so:

```
\documentclass{...}

\title{Title goes here}
\author{Author name goes here}

...

\begin{document}
\maketitle
```

The `\title` command is just identifying the title for the document and should go in the document preamble. The `\maketitle` command is responsible for typesettingg the title and goes after `\begin{document}`.

Note also that formatting should be handled by the document class and you don't really want to do all that `\textit` etc. in your `\title`, `\author` etc.

Comment: thanks a lot!  solved!

Answer (score 1):

Your `\maketitle` command is misplaced.

```latex
\documentclass[conference,a4paper]{IEEEtran}

\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}


\title{Title\\{\footnotesize whatever\textsuperscript{x}\thanks{Thanks}}}

\author{%
  \IEEEauthorblockN{1\textsuperscript{st} A. Uthor}
  \IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Something} \\
    \textit{something else}\\
    whatever\\
    again}
  \and
  \IEEEauthorblockN{2\textsuperscript{nd} W. Riter}
  \IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Something} \\
    \textit{something}\\
    again \\
    whatever}
}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
.....
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

[image]